# How to initialize a non-constant pointer in a constant class with a constant pointer?

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

I found that this code does not work.

```cpp
class BinaryData {
public:
    int size;
    char* bits;

    const BinaryData (int _size, const char* _bits) : size(_size), bits(_bits) {} 
}
```

The compiler says that I cannot convert from `const char*` to `char*`. However, is this really the case?

What I'm trying to do initialize here is a constant of type `const BinaryData`. As I know, it's like a class of which fields are given by `const int size` and `const char* const bits`. If then, shouldn't things like this have to be allowed?

What I should do if I really have to initialize `const BinaryData` type value with `int` and `const char*`? If it is forbidden, why it has to be forbidden?

Comment: Whether the object will be constant or not doesn't matter, the constructor doesn't see the variable declaration, all it does is initialize an instance of that class.

Comment: You can initialize the const pointer with non-const one, the other way is forbidden, therefore need a castaway of const by `const_cast`.

Comment: Can you also explain why it has to be forbidden? This almost looks like a design flaw in C++ to me now.

Comment: I think you have a slight misunderstanding of `const` qualifier. Declarations in C++ are to be read according to spiral rule, which is this case decays to right-to-left reading order. `const char*` is a mutable pointer to const-qualified `char`, not a const-qualified pointer. So you are trying to initialize a pointer to mutable object with a pointer to non-mutable object which is forbidden. At the same time mutable pointer can be initialized with a const-qualified pointer without problems. `char * const p{}; char * p2{p};`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I definitely know the meaning of `const char*`. The problem here is that what I'm trying to initialize is a value of type `const BinaryData,` which has a field of type `const char* const bits`. As I know, converting from `const char*` to  `const char* const` is possible, just as converting from `int` to `const int` is possible.

Comment: (Correction) As I know, converting from `const char* const` to  `const char*` is possible, just as converting from `const int` to `int` is possible.

Comment: I think it's solved. I found that I can still modify the pointed memory of `const BinaryData`. This means that the type of its field, `bits` is not `const char* const` but `char* const`. (I don't know why I assumed the pointed memory would be naturally protected.)